# Writing to Processed MSMQ Message

Tags: powershell, msmq

Basically I have a PowerShell script that will reprocess a failed MSMQ message based on where it came from, but I'm having issues trying to "tag" any message that's been reprocessed with a new child node under the FailedQ node with a value of `Processed`.

This is the function to read the originating queue that I'm also trying to throw in the writing as well. Granted this is basically repurposed code that I'm trying to suit to my purposes. I'm sure I've gone wrong somewhere but I'm not sure where, as the message does reprocess but nothing is ever written to it.

```
Function ReadandWriteFailedQueueFromHeaders
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [System.Messaging.Message] $message
    )

    $rawheaders = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($message.Extension)
    $reader = New-Object System.IO.StringReader($rawheaders)
    $writer = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter($rawheaders)
    $xml = [xml] $reader.ReadToEnd()
    $xmlwriter = [xml] $writer.Write("Processed", $xml)
    $header =  $xml.ArrayOfHeaderInfo.HeaderInfo | ? Key -eq    "FailedQ" | Select -ExpandProperty Value
    $headernode = $xml.ArrayOfHeaderInfo.HeaderInfo | ? Key -eq "FailedQ"
    return ('{2}{0}\private$\{1}' -f $header.Split('@')[1], $header.Split('@')[0], "FormatName:DIRECT=OS:" )
    $node = $xmlwriter.SelectSingleNode($headernode)
    $child = $node.CreateElement("Processed")
    $xmlwriter.DocumentElement.AppendChild($child)
    $node = $xml.SelectSingleNode("FailedQ")
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to edit an existing message in the queue? I thought message were immutable.

Comment: @JohnBreakwell I am trying to edit an existing message.  I've had success doing this via third party tools like Queue Explorer and I've also overwritten a message body using Powershell but I haven't been able to target a specific attribute or value to add or alter.